# Остановить выполнение JS скрипта из фукнции

Tags: javascript, jquery

При срабатывание условия в функции, нужно остановить работу скрипта вне функции. Return false останавливает работу самой функции, а всё, что вне, продолжает работу

UPDATE 1:
При такой остановке скрипта, проверка фукнции идёт 1 раз. Как при каждом вызове события делать проверку и уже дальше либо останавливать дальнейший код, либо пропускать

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  function Fukntion() {
      if (...) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
  if (!Fukntion()) { return; }


  $('#Top select').on('change', function() {
      Fukntion();
  }
  Какой либо код дальше
}
```

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: перенести "дальнейший код" внутрь обработчика `change`

Comment: код в строчке _Какой либо код дальше_ выполняется раньше чем обработчик `change`, поэтому его никак нельзя будет прервать из обработчика.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  function Fukntion() {
      if (...) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }

  function changeHandler(e) {
    if (!Fukntion()) { return; }

    Какой либо код дальше
  }


  $('#Top select').on('change', changeHandler);
  $('#Top select').change();
}
```

Comment: Видел этот способ. Но как по мне, это какие то костыли. Хотелось бы узнать про более элегантный способ

Comment: `throw new Error('Script stopped')` более элегантно?

Comment: Это не костыль, это пока единственный адекватный в рамках V8 способ остановить скрипт. Более того он не чуть не отварительный на вид.

Comment: Единственное, что мне не нравится в коде ответа - возможность написать `return !(...);` =)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов "отварительный" - с телефона?

Comment: Попробовал её. Но она срабатывает только при первой обработке JS. Fukntion() вызывается по событию и следовательно после уже не срабатывает "if (!Fukntion())
  return;"

Comment: @Gagablik Вы понимаете, конечно, что здесь никто не видит Вашего монитора? Добавьте *весь и только* имеющий отношение к делу код (и разметку) в вопрос.

Comment: @Igor Готово, добавил

Comment: @Gagablik я уже ответил комментарием с ссылкой

Comment: @Igor совершено верно!:)